# Overwriting CSS rules with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- The one below is a custom style sheet that should override -->
 <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>  
 <body>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" id="side_step">
       <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm trying to target the list-item upon hover. In the `bootstrap.css` file, I have the following

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover {
    background:#08f !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What's strange is that when I inspect the elements in firebug, it says the bootstrap file correctly assigns the following style to the very same element... just not on hover

```
.navbar-nav > li {
   float:left;
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8f8f8, #e8e8e8);
   background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#e8e8e8));
   background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #e8e8e8);
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#e8e8e8');
   color:#090127;
   margin-top:6px;
   border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

The `sb-admin.css` file should override the rules set forth in `bootstrap.css` but it doesn't seem to in respect to this. In `sb-admin.css` I have

```
#side_step li:hover {
   background:#08f !important;
}
```

A working example can be found [here](http://lancenewman.me/marketing/demographics.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is on the anchor.

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
   background:#08f;
}
```

Comment: It did for me in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't see your update. It works! Thanks!